# Why does decorating a recursive function yield unexpected flow of results?

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

```
# THE CODE 

import time 

# A decorator to time the function being exeuted
def timeit(func):
    # The Wrapper
    def timer(arg):
        current_time = time.time()
        result = func(arg)
        print("result = ",result) # I know this hinders the time calculation part ... just for testing
        time_difference = time.time() - current_time
        return result 
    return timer

# Recursive Function to find factorial
@timeit
def factorial(n):
    print("I'm inside factorial")
    return n if n < 2 else n * factorial(n-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(factorial(5))
```

```
-----output------

I'm inside factorial
I'm inside factorial
I'm inside factorial
I'm inside factorial
I'm inside factorial
result =  1
result =  2
result =  6
result =  24
result =  120
120
```

I wrote this program to time my factorial function and the result of the function is as expected but the flow of the program isn't what I expected. I want to understand how decorators and recursion work i.e. how the recursion map to the original function rather than the decorated one and how the result is printed serially without printing the "I'm inside factorial" as seen in the output towards the end. Explanation of the flow or pointing to the right resources would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion is calling the wrapper function on every level. That is, the call stack looks like:

```
timer(5)
  factorial(5)
    timer(4)
      factorial(4)
        timer(3)
          factorial(3)
            ...
```

This happens because the decorator syntax replaced the original `factorial` function in the global namespace with the `timer` function returned by the decorator. The `timer` function can still call the original `factorial` function because it has access to a reference to it via the `func` variable in the decorator function's namespace (this means that `timer` is a closure).

You see all the `"I'm inside"` messages first because they're being printed before each call in `factorial`. The `"result ="` messages print out at the end and in reverse order because they are after each call to `func` within `timer`, and so they happen as the stack is unwinding, not while it's being built up.

Here's a modified call stack showing the `print` calls too:

```
timer(5)
  factorial(5)
    print("I'm inside factorial")
    timer(4)
      factorial(4)
        print("I'm inside factorial")
        timer(3)
          factorial(3)
            ...
          print("result = ", 6)
      print("result = ", 24)
  print("result = ", 120)
```

It might clarify things to have printouts both before and after the calls in one or both functions:

```
def timeit(func):
    # The Wrapper
    def timer(arg):
        print("timer start")                                  # new output here
        current_time = time.time()
        result = func(arg)
        print("result = ",result)
        time_difference = time.time() - current_time
        return result
    return timer

# Recursive Function to find factorial
@timeit
def factorial(n):
    print("I'm inside factorial")
    result = n if n < 2 else n * factorial(n-1)
    print("Factorial computed")                               # and here
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the program flow that I expect.

```
def factorial(n):
    print("I'm inside factorial")
    return n if n < 2 else n * factorial(n-1)
```

calls the `factorial` function again before returning anything allowing control to return to the decorator.  This is how recursion works.  It builds up the stack of calls until it reaches the end condition.  It then goes back through them in reverse order.

In this case, the program calls `factorial(5)`.  Since 5 is not < 2, it calls `factorial(4)`.  4 is not < 2, so `factorial(3)`, which then triggers `factorial(2)` , then `factorial(1)`.  At this point n is < 2 so it returns 1.  This then returns control to the decorator where it prints that the current result is 1.  Control is then returned to the `factorial(2)` call where it multiplies 2 by the result returned from `factorial(1)` to return 2 to the decorator.  This continues through `factorial(3)` = 6, `factorial(4)` = 24 and finally to `factorial(5)` = 120

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know in runtime what the function `factorial` is, but rather where it's located in memory. When you decorate it you are overwriting the function, so whenever python calls it the "original version" does not exist anymore. you can even change the definition of a recursive function while calling it, the thing is that at each call, python is going to address where the function is located in memory and read the current version in order to execute it.

Comment: but then wouldn't 'Im inside factorial'  and the result = .. be  printed alternatively rather than one after another . I mean like why is it that half of the function runs for n times but sitll the result prints all of its original values one by one even after the recursion is over?